# Prestashop - Composed Product title in database mysql

Tags: mysql, database, prestashop

I should create a composed title that is always the same in Prestashop.
Example
Manufacturer - Category Tags - Code - Color
All these fields, however, are in different tables and vary with the language.
In your opinion, is it feasible via SQL?
Thanks so much

Comment: `however, are in different tables and vary with the language` What does this mean?

Comment: scuse me...this value is in different table in database

Comment: I think to do a Join

Comment: Show tha tables, we can write the join.

Comment: I don't know prestashop at all, but speaking from a php/mysql perspective, it might be easiest to do this on the fly when the Title is being requested in PHP from the database. Modify the SQL there to do the joins and override whatever title is being stored for the product with your concatenated title. (As opposed to trying to store the title in in the `product_lang` table). Most likely you'll have to join `product` to `manufacturer_lang`, `category_lang`, `product_attribute`, and possibly a few others judging by prestashops very extensive schema.

Comment: [Here's a link to Presta Shop's 1.7 schema](https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/blob/1.7.3.x/install-dev/data/db_structure.sql) this might help tracking down the fields you are after.